# gcov out of memory / mismatched version?

Tags: c, code-coverage, clang, gcov

Just trying to get gcov up and running, getting the following error:

```
$ gcov src/main.c -o build
build/main.gcno:version '404*', prefer '407*'

gcov: out of memory allocating 14819216480 bytes after a total of 135168 bytes
```

I'm using clang/profile_rt to generate the files gcov needs, I'm assuming that might have something to do with it. It's working on my other computer, though, so I assume it can be fixed somehow.

Answer (score 25):

I just had the same problem on my machine.

Make sure your versions of gcov and the compiler you use match.

I had this exact problem when compiling with g++-4.7 and I had gcov 4.6.

On my machine `sudo apt-get install ggcov` got me the latest version.  I then had to `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/gcov-4.7 /usr/bin/gcov` to make gcov point in the right place.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I got around the problem by simply executing gcov-4.7 instead of gcov.  I suppose a more elegant approach would involve using update-alternatives, if I were motivated.

Comment: Thanks Anthony! And `ln -sf` can automatically remove the old gcov for you.

Comment: Thanks @EricZ. Updated :D

Answer (score 12):

My problem was that I updated `gcc` and `g++` so that I could use a newer compiler, but forgot to update the `gcov` version meaning running "`gcov`" or "`lcov`" picked up the previous compilers version of `gcov`.

So basically running `g++ --version` and `gcov --version` should yield the same version number else things are going to go very wrong.

Here is how I updated my compiler version, the last line being what I was missing to get it all working.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 90
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9 90
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-4.9 90
```

Answer (score 10):

I just had the same problem and I had the correct versions installed. Solution in my case: remove all `*.gcda` files from any subdir you compile in. My `make clean` did not cover them.

Comment: Thanks.  Had me head scratching for a while!

Answer (score 0):

1. Running `gcov` with `-v` flag you can get the exact execution gcov command. It may help to understand what happens.
2. In my case, specifying gcov version helped to solve the issue:
   `gcovr --gcov-executable gcov-7`