# What does the error "version '404*', prefer '402*'" mean running gcov

Tags: xcode, code-coverage, travis-ci, coveralls

Trying to build coverage data for Coveralls I get the following error messages during the Travis-CI build:

```
DTHTMLWriter.gcno:version '404*', prefer '402*'
File '/Users/travis/build/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/Core/Source/DTHTMLWriter.m'
Lines executed:67.00% of 497
/Users/travis/build/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/Core/Source/DTHTMLWriter.m:creating 'DTHTMLWriter.m.gcov'
File 'Core/Source/DTHTMLWriter.m'
Lines executed:0.00% of 10
Core/Source/DTHTMLWriter.m:creating 'DTHTMLWriter.m.gcov'
Core/Source/DTHTMLWriter.m:cannot open source file
File 'Core/Source/DTHTMLWriter.h'
Lines executed:66.67% of 3
Core/Source/DTHTMLWriter.h:creating 'DTHTMLWriter.h.gcov'
Core/Source/DTHTMLWriter.h:cannot open source file
```

There is coverage, namely 67%, but the result of this is that Coveralls shows this file as having 0 coverage.

How do I fix that?

Tests have shown that this error occurs with the gcov tool bundled with Xcode 4 and 5, version 4.2.1 in both cases. I dound that if I run the same unit test on Mac instead, then I don't get the warning and the files are found.

Which lewds me to believe that the gcov tool has a bug handling certain gcda files produced by iOS simulator. Some, not all.

The resultning coverage report is missing those files when run for iOS, but is complete for Mac.

So my second question is if there is a way to change those files to allow gcov to correctly process them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcov out of memory / mismatched version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454175/gcov-out-of-memory-mismatched-version)